# scipy.optimize.linprog: What happens if we choose the coefficients orthogonal to the feasible set?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-programming

I am using [scipy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) to solve a linear program. In particular, I have the constraint x_1 + ... x_n = 1, i.e. my feasible set is a subset of the n-dimensional simplex. Now, I am asking myself what happens when I choose the coefficients c of the minimization as c = (1, ..., 1). The minimization is then irrelevant, since <c, x> = 1 always.

What result does scipy.optimize.linprog give me in this situation?

I tested it, but I couldn't tell which element in the feasible set was calculated by the program. My guess it that it is a random vertex of the polytope resulting from the other inequality constraints. Can somebody confirm this?

Comment: "I couldn't tell which element in the feasible set was calculated by the program" You could not just print the optimal solution? As any feasible solution is optimal, that would be the answer.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I could print it. But I don't know which "direction" was used for the optimization, i.e. I don't know to which c the result corresponds to (since it cannot really be c = (1,...,1) as the minimization is then irrelevant ).

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is `implementation defined`. The code guarantees you an optimal solution, but not any particular one. The default method is an interior point algorithm as it says in the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html). An interior point method does not generally even return a vertex, so it could be *any* optimal point. I tried it and got `[1/n, ..., 1/n]` for a problem with `n` variables, but this may very well differ even between `scipy` versions.

If you choose a simplex-type algorithm (adding `method="revised simplex"`) you will get a basic solution, corresponding to a vertex of the polyhedron, which in your case corresponds to a unit vector. Which one is again implementation-defined.

Most codes should be deterministic however, so you should always get the same solution for the same input...